# Same query but different execution plans for postgresql query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, index-tuning, explain

I am struggling with a query running for 30 seconds on one of my db  hosts.
Same query ( same configuration for db in postgresql.conf ) runs in 3 seconds with a different execution plan.
Yes the amount of data is a little bit different. but not as huge as explaining the difference.

I checked and tried different values for *work* parameters , but reached not the result I am looking for .
I vacuumed analyzed all tables in the select .. but nothing .

Any idea would be great to help me solve this .

1. query :

```sql
select count(*)  from products itm, propertymaps pmp 
 where pmp.instanceid = itm.instPropertyMapId   
 and itm.validUntil >= '2023-08-08 00:00:00'  
 and itm.validFrom <= '2023-08-08 00:00:00'   
 and itm.productGroupId in (            select childId              
 from inheritances            
  where parentid in ('218900559', '218900537', '218900603', '218900581'))   
  and itm.ownerid in ('9377779201619')   
  and cast(pmp.properties->'props'->>'4049111000000/PUBLISHING_PriceAvailableState,,,' as boolean)   
  and EXISTS (select 'x' from tags tg where tg.objinstanceid = itm.instanceid and tg.category = 'APPROVAL.POOL1');
```

2. SLOW Execution PLAN

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=1602884.65..1602884.66 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=34882.280..34887.119 rows=1 loops=1)\
   ->  Gather  (cost=1602884.54..1602884.65 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=34881.099..34887.111 rows=2 loops=1)\
         Workers Planned: 1\
         Workers Launched: 1\
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=1601884.54..1601884.55 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=34806.871..34806.876 rows=1 loops=2)\
               ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=41813.92..1601510.41 rows=149650 width=0) (actual time=368.775..34796.374 rows=41900 loops=2)\
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=41813.36..1456210.51 rows=149650 width=8) (actual time=368.024..34079.434 rows=41900 loops=2)\
                           ->  Hash Join  (cost=41812.79..665715.22 rows=310854 width=16) (actual time=365.470..12493.936 rows=114248 loops=2)\
                                 Hash Cond: (itm.productgroupid = inheritances.childid)\
                                 ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on products itm  (cost=41803.16..661023.35 rows=466281 width=24) (actual time=365.111..12372.259 rows=438874 loops=2)\
                                       Recheck Cond: ((ownerid = '9377779201619'::bigint) AND (validfrom <= '2023-08-08 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (validuntil >= '2023-08-08 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))\
                                       Heap Blocks: exact=76675
                                       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on products_idx_date  (cost=0.00..41604.99 rows=792677 width=0) (actual time=356.026..356.027 rows=877771 loops=1)\
                                             Index Cond: ((ownerid = '9377779201619'::bigint) AND (validfrom <= '2023-08-08 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (validuntil >= '2023-08-08 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))\
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=9.58..9.58 rows=4 width=8) (actual time=0.073..0.075 rows=4 loops=2)\
                                       Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB\
                                       ->  HashAggregate  (cost=9.54..9.58 rows=4 width=8) (actual time=0.068..0.070 rows=4 loops=2)\
                                             Group Key: inheritances.childid\
                                             ->  Index Scan using inh_p on inheritances  (cost=0.28..9.53 rows=4 width=8) (actual time=0.054..0.063 rows=4 loops=2)\
                                                   Index Cond: (parentid = ANY ('{218900559,218900537,218900603,218900581}'::bigint[]))\
                           ->  Index Scan using pmp_pk on propertymaps pmp  (cost=0.57..2.54 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.188..0.188 rows=0 loops=228497)\
                                 Index Cond: (instanceid = itm.instpropertymapid)\
                                 Filter: (((properties -> 'props'::text) ->> '4049111000000/PUBLISHING_PriceAvailableState,,,'::text))::boolean
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 1\
                     ->  Index Only Scan using tags_idx1 on tags tg  (cost=0.57..1.56 rows=4 width=8) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=1 loops=83800)\
                           Index Cond: ((category = 'APPROVAL.POOL1'::text) AND (objinstanceid = itm.instanceid))\
                           Heap Fetches: 66\
 Planning Time: 4.554 ms\
 Execution Time: 34911.589 ms\
(29 rows)
```

2. FAST ONE
   prodpgdb18=# explain analyze

```sql
 select count(*)  from products 
 itm, propertymaps pmp 
 where pmp.instanceid = itm.instPropertyMapId   
 and itm.validUntil >= '2023-08-08 00:00:00'  
 and itm.validFrom <= '2023-08-08 00:00:00'   
 and itm.productGroupId in (            select childId              
 from inheritances            
  where parentid in ('218900559', '218900537', '218900603', '218900581'))   
  and itm.ownerid in ('9377779201619')   
  and cast(pmp.properties->'props'->>'4049111000000/PUBLISHING_PriceAvailableState,,,' as boolean)   
  and EXISTS (select 'x' from tags tg where tg.objinstanceid = itm.instanceid and tg.category = 'APPROVAL.POOL1');
```

QUERY PLAN

```
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=141867.29..141867.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=10.458..12.857 rows=1 loops=1)\
   ->  Gather  (cost=141866.87..141867.28 rows=4 width=8) (actual time=1.205..12.842 rows=4 loops=1)\
         Workers Planned: 4\
         Workers Launched: 3\
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=140866.87..140866.88 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.093..0.097 rows=1 loops=4)\
               ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=2138.98..140866.52 rows=141 width=0) (actual time=0.089..0.093 rows=0 loops=4)\
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2138.29..140694.31 rows=141 width=8) (actual time=0.089..0.093 rows=0 loops=4)\
                           ->  Hash Join  (cost=2137.72..138254.70 rows=284 width=16) (actual time=0.088..0.092 rows=0 loops=4)\
                                 Hash Cond: (itm.productgroupid = inheritances.childid)\
                                 ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on products itm  (cost=2112.90..138221.37 rows=2046 width=24) (never executed)\
                                       Recheck Cond: (ownerid = '9377779201619'::bigint)\
                                       Filter: ((validuntil >= '2023-08-08 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (validfrom <= '2023-08-08 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))\
                                       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on itm_ownerid_idx  (cost=0.00..2110.86 rows=36038 width=0) (never executed)
                                             Index Cond: (ownerid = '9377779201619'::bigint)\
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=24.77..24.77 rows=4 width=8) (actual time=0.036..0.037 rows=0 loops=4)\
                                       Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB\
                                       ->  HashAggregate  (cost=24.73..24.77 rows=4 width=8) (actual time=0.035..0.036 rows=0 loops=4)\
                                             Group Key: inheritances.childid\
                                             ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on inheritances  (cost=17.14..24.72 rows=4 width=8) (actual time=0.034..0.035 rows=0 loops=4)\
                                                   Recheck Cond: (parentid = ANY ('{218900559,218900537,218900603,218900581}'::bigint[]))\
                                                   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on inh_p  (cost=0.00..17.14 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.029..0.029 rows=0 loops=4)\
                                                         Index Cond: (parentid = ANY ('{218900559,218900537,218900603,218900581}'::bigint[]))\
                           ->  Index Scan using pmp_pk on propertymaps pmp  (cost=0.57..8.59 rows=1 width=8) (never executed)\
                                 Index Cond: (instanceid = itm.instpropertymapid)\
                                 Filter: (((properties -> 'props'::text) ->> '4049111000000/PUBLISHING_PriceAvailableState,,,'::text))::boolean\
                     ->  Index Only Scan using tags_idx1 on tags tg  (cost=0.70..5.01 rows=16 width=8) (never executed)\
                           Index Cond: ((category = 'APPROVAL.POOL1'::text) AND (objinstanceid = itm.instanceid))\
                           Heap Fetches: 0\
 Planning Time: 2.321 ms\
 Execution Time: 13.062 ms\
(30 rows)
```

Comment: "Yes the amount of data is a little bit different"  A little bit?  One processes 41900 rows, one processes zero.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the first thing to try is to make sure the statistics are up to date on all of the hosts.

```
analyze verbose propertymaps;
analyze verbose products;
```

I assume the schema and indexes are identical already.

Another thing you can try is `pg_repack` on the tables to remove bloat on all of the hosts.

If nothing else works you can disable nested_loops (when you run the query).

```
set enable_nestloop = 0;
```

Comment: unfortunately , verbose did not solve the issue
same runtime 
 Planning Time: 6.108 ms
 Execution Time: 32834.166 ms
(29 rows)

and set enable_nestloop = 0; .. 
no even more worse :((